# WP_QUERY : Return posts by tags , filtered by post formats

Tags: php, logical-operators, wordpress

I have the following code snippet, which is supposed to return 6 posts which are related to the current post by tag and the 6 posts should be the ones with a  video post format taxonomy :

```
if('artists' == get_post_type()){
    $taxs = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
    $name = the_title();
    if($taxs){
        $tax_ids = array();
        foreach ($tax_ids as $individual_tax){
            $tax_ids[] = $individual_tax->term_id;
        }
        gs = array(
        'post_type' =>'post',
        'tag__in'=> $tax_ids,
       'tax_query' =>array(                         
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array('post-format-video')
                                ),
                        ),
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        );
     $video_query = new WP_QUERY($args);
    // other code comes here .........
```

The problem is that when I run the query, it returns all posts with a video post format, rather than those that have the related tags as the current post being viewed. Please help me solve this.

Let me put this in an example : The current post has a tag called 'oranges'. In the related posts section, I want it to display posts that also have a tag called oranges but only those with a video post format taxonomy.

Comment: `tags__in` should be `tag__in`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks. I have corrected the typo but it still not working as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` loop should be:

```
foreach ($taxs as $individual_tax)
```

and not:

```
foreach ($tax_ids as $individual_tax)
```

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeees :-) changed it as stated  and it has worked. it's the little things